Prove that every string in L is generated by G
Let L be the language of strings with no substring either 0111 or 1000 and which has a balanced number of 0s and 1s.
Consider the CFG meant to generate L.
S -> e | A | B

A -> e | 000B1101 | 10 | 01S10 | 10S10 

B -> e | 111A0010 | 01 | 01S01 | 10S01

I am trying to prove that if any string is in L, it has a production in this grammar.  I would perhaps guess that we proceed by induction on the number of 0s, say, in any string in L.  The base-case of k=0 instances of 0 is trivial, so we assume that any string with $0\le k$ instances of 0 is in L, then it has a production in this grammar.  Then consider a string with k+1 instances of 0 in L.
From here I don't see a good way of splintering into cases.  For instance, if the string is 0x1, what can we say?  And even if we can say something about this, then we have to consider 01x10 and so on for a ton of different cases.
Is there a more efficient way of approaching this problem?

What about 0011?
